# How to use 'Recall' as metric in keras classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can use use the 'Recall' and other metrics in keras classifier. The following code only works for accuracy but if I change the metric to recall it fails.

## Versions

```
"""
[('numpy', '1.19.1'),
 ('pandas', '1.1.1'),
 ('sklearn', '0.23.2'),
 ('tensorflow', '2.3.0'),
 ('keras', '2.4.3')]

"""
```

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense

SEED = 100


np.random.seed(100)
X = np.random.random((20, 3))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,size=20)

print(x.shape, y.shape) # (20, 3) (20,)

n_inputs = X.shape[1]

model = Sequential([
    Dense(n_inputs, input_shape=(n_inputs, ), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])


METRIC = 'Recall' # Recall fails
# METRIC = 'accuracy' # accuracy works


model.compile('adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=[METRIC])
model.fit(X, y,validation_split=0.2,epochs=1)
```

## Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b372311b0ed4> in <module>
     38             epochs=10,
     39             shuffle=True,
---> 40             verbose=5)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:759 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:409 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:176 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:1410 update_state  **
        sample_weight=sample_weight)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:353 update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    /Users/poudel/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the final layer output 2 to 1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense

SEED = 100


np.random.seed(100)
X = np.random.random((20, 3))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,size=20)

print(X.shape, y.shape) # (20, 3) (20,)

n_inputs = X.shape[1]

model = Sequential([
    Dense(n_inputs, input_shape=(n_inputs, ), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='relu')
])


METRIC = 'Recall' # Recall fails
# METRIC = 'accuracy' # accuracy works


model.compile('adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=[METRIC])
model.fit(X, y,validation_split=0.2,epochs=1)
```

Comment: Softmax with one output neuron will not work, if this is binary classification you need to use sigmoid activation at the output

Comment: U can use any activation function.